# Android App crashes on Unity Splash Screen

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-logcat, vuforia

So, I know this is a repeated question but mine doesn't seem to match any of them.

I use Unity 5.0.1 which crashes the same as 4.6 that I had before. 
My app runs sample applications but only when I make my own custom apps it crashes.

I must explain that I use Vuforia as well, and again it's not Vuforia's problem.

My LogCat with Error filter shows this:

```
04-28 12:27:59.946: A/libc(5382): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000004 (code=1), thread 5397 (UnityMain)
04-28 12:28:00.376: E/InputDispatcher(426): channel '42030b20 com.rjj.roads/com.rjj.roads.UnityPlayerNativeActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
04-28 12:28:00.401: E/Surface(122): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
04-28 12:28:00.401: E/Camera2-Device(122): enqueue_buffer: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
04-28 12:28:00.431: E/Surface(122): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
04-28 12:28:00.431: E/Camera2-Device(122): enqueue_buffer: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
04-28 12:28:00.446: E/Surface(122): queueBuffer: error queuing buffer to SurfaceTexture, -32
04-28 12:28:00.446: E/Camera2-Device(122): enqueue_buffer: Error queueing buffer to native window: Broken pipe (-32)
04-28 12:32:33.086: E/MPL-storeload(426): calData from inv_save_mpl_states, size=2
04-28 12:32:33.796: E/MPL-storeload(426): calData from inv_save_mpl_states, size=2
04-28 12:32:49.286: E/BluetoothMap(5496): Could not bind to Bluetooth MAP Service with Intent { act=android.bluetooth.IBluetoothMap }
04-28 12:32:50.321: E/NfcNciHal(625): StartupConfig::append: invalid length at newContent[0]
```

My unity setting are properly OpenGL 2.x and the app name is set up with all caps down. I've even correctly put in the Vuforia app key.

> I understand you might want more info and I am wiling to show you on
>   request, but from the errors could you please tell me what the problem
>   is first?

Comment: It's really hard to diagnose the problem with such a small amount of information. What I would do is to try to remove things from the projects, from the current state to the point where I only include one completely empty scene in it, in order to pinpoint what exactly causes it.

Comment: do you have the build settings set for android?!

Comment: @golergka I've got too many objects/scripts running on this app. I've worked on this app on a previous computer and it worked fine.

Please tell me what more would you need in order to get a better view of things?

Comment: @Virus yes, I've build the IDE on the new computer as well.

Comment: i mean in unity have you set the platform for android?

Comment: @Virus yes, in build settings I've set it to Android and export.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the reason why I would start removing them. Of course, it would break the functionality, but I wouldn't care: my goal would be just pinpoint the culprit so I can investigate it further. So, first I would remove all scenes but the first one from the build settings, and then start doing binary search (just like `git bisect`) on all gameObjects in this scene.

Comment: hmm, alright @golergka will check it out. Although, I hope that  `git bisect `was just a reference cause I have no idea how to use `git`

Comment: Sorry, it's just the best way I know how to describe this method shortly. As an unrelated piece of advice, `git` is very widely used, and I would recommend studying it anyway if you have some time.

Comment: Will do. Been wanting to. So, I went and deleted everything till I had only the ARCamera and it's target. But I now only get a blank screen. The camera isn't turning on. Any ideas? Golergka & Virus ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stripped it down to the last scene and found out there was no fix yet. And ended up removing all the objects as well, and was left with only the ARCamera and ImageTarget.

Well, while learning to create an ImageTarget I had accidentally created two databases with the same image. Similarly for License Keys. And each Database had it's own keys.

**Bottom line:** I used the wrong key for the wrong target. Switching them back, helped the app to run again.

Comment: What? what database? what license key? what image?